# Code clarification for median.default() conditional return value

Tags: r

I came across a piece of code in `median.default` that I simply cannot comprehend.  It involves the return value when `na.rm = FALSE`, and the vector does contain at least one `NA` value.

The code in question is

```
x[FALSE][NA]
```

It is found in `body` elements 4 and 6 of `median.default`

```
> bod <- body(median.default)
> bod[[4]]
# if (na.rm) 
#     x <- x[!is.na(x)] 
# else if (any(is.na(x))) 
#     return(x[FALSE][NA])
> bod[[6]]
# if (n == 0L) 
#     return(x[FALSE][NA])
```

When I break this code down, that's where I get lost. I just don't understand its purpose.

Why is it written like that when you could simply write `return(NA)` ? Or use `as.numeric(NA)` or other `as.*` functions?

```
> x <- c(1, NA, 5, NA, 12)
> if(any(is.na(x))) x[FALSE][NA]
# [1] NA
> x[FALSE]
# numeric(0)
> if(any(is.na(x))) NA
# [1] NA
```

If the answer is to turn the `NA` value into the same class of `x`, then why not use `as.*`?

```
> Y <- c(as.integer(NA), as.double(NA), as.numeric(NA)) 
> sapply(Y, function(x) c(class(x), typeof(x), mode(x)))
#      [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
# [1,] "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
# [2,] "double"  "double"  "double" 
# [3,] "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
```

Comment: Now you're venturing into opinion-land, but I would suggest `x[FALSE][NA]` is simpler than testing to see which variety of different classes, no?  You might be better off asking why `median` returns this, while `mean` just returns NA_real_ (though there I'm not sure there would be a clear answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's how they return an NA of the same type of x.

Source: The [inside-r](http://www.inside-r.org/node/36944) page on Median.

Example:

```
> x <- 1:3
> y <- NA
> z <- x[FALSE][NA]
> class(x)
[1] "integer"
> class(y)
[1] "logical"
> class(z)
[1] "integer"
> x
[1] 1 2 3
> y
[1] NA
> z
[1] NA
>
```

Further example, showing why both are needed:

```
> x
[1] 1 2 3
> x[FALSE]
integer(0)
> x[NA]
[1] NA NA NA
> x[FALSE][NA]
[1] NA
>
```

Adding `[FALSE]` reduces x to a zero length vector (but still numeric).  Adding `[NA]` makes it actually return NA.

Comment: Thanks..  I guess I'd really like to go a bit further and ask *how* adding `[NA]` to `x[FALSE]` turns a logical into a numeric.

Comment: Well, `x[FALSE]` is not equal to `NA` (it is `integer(0)`).  `x[FALSE]` reduces `x` to a zero length vector, and then indexing it with NA makes it an NA.